# How can I put the file contents in to a JList

Tags: java, swing, io, java.util.scanner, jlist

How can I put the contents of the examplefile.dat into the Jlist
examplefile.dat

evan:joe:lance:steve

the names separated by colon would be converted to array and put it in the JList or JComboBox

here's my code to Load and print the file

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FileScanner {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws IOException  
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JTextField input0 = new javax.swing.JTextField(20);
        JButton load = new javax.swing.JButton("Load");
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(240,200);
        panel.add(input0);
        panel.add(load);


        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                 FileReader fin = null;
                                 String filename = input0.getText();
                            try {
                                 fin = new FileReader(filename);
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                                   Logger.getLogger(FileScanner.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }
                                 Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
                                 src.useDelimiter(":");
                                 while (src.hasNext()) {
                                 String lol = src.nextLine();
                                 System.out.println(lol); 
                                }
                                } 
                                });


        }
}
```

Ok this is my Code..

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Jfetizanan
 */
public class IOtestForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form IOtest
     */
    public IOtestForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        list = new javax.swing.JList();
        input0 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        load = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(list);
        DefaultListSelectionModel m = new DefaultListSelectionModel();
        m.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        m.setLeadAnchorNotificationEnabled(false);
        list.setSelectionModel(m);
        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        int selected[] = list.getSelectedIndices();
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        String element = (String) list.getModel().getElementAt(selected[i]);
        input0.setText(element);
        }}});

        load.setText("Load");
        load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                 FileReader fin = null;
                            try {
                                 fin = new FileReader("data.dat");
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                                   Logger.getLogger(IOtestForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }
                                 Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
                                 src.useDelimiter("\n");
                                DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
                                while (src.hasNext()) {
                                String lol = src.nextLine();
                                model.addElement(lol);
                                }
                                list.setModel(model);
                                } 
                                });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 380, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(input0)
                    .addComponent(load, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                .addComponent(load)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(input0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(94, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(IOtestForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new IOtestForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JTextField input0;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JList list;
    private javax.swing.JButton load;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

@MadProgrammer  look at the new code I post.. what It does is it load the file and show everything inside it in a JList and when I click it.. It shows the line in a textarea.. But I want the Jlist to display only the number in the list and when I click it. It displays the rest of the Characters in the rest of the string in the line

this must be the content of the data.dat

1 lol

2 lol

3 lol

4 lol

*don't mind the space between the lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JList list = new JList(); // You need to create the JList first
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
// Add the scrollpane to the UI

...

// At some time in the future, load the results...
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
while (src.hasNext()) {
    String lol = src.nextLine();
    model.addElement(lol);
}
list.setModel(model);
```

Perhaps you'd like to take a read of

- [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- [How to use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

For some more useful information

Comment: Instead of adding the button to the frame, add a panel with a `BorderLayout`.  Add the button to the `PAGE_START` and `JScrollPane` with the `JList` to the `CENTER`.  Once the button is clicked, file is parsed, set a new model for the list.

Comment: Anywhere you want, it's you're screen.  Personally, I'd either change the layout manager and layout the components slightly better

Comment: So can I use variabel list everywhere I want with the JList.. etc

Comment: what do i do with this list.setModel(model); ?

Comment: `list` was just the variable name I made up for a `JList`. So just like a you did with the `JButton`, you create an instance of `JList` (in the example I called it list, but you can call it what ever you like), add it to you layout and once the file is loaded, set the model to have it's contents filled out

Comment: just like this panel.add(list);? but it cant find symbol variable list?
list.setModel(model);
panel.add(list); the two variable list is always underlined red. 
I don't know why? 

I'm just a newbie (:
@MadProgrammer

Comment: @MadProgrammer

'final JList list = new JList();'
'final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);'

they must be final

Comment: @JFetz2191 only because of the way "you're" using it.  In the context of your code, yes.

Comment: @MadProgrammer  look at the new code I post.. what It does is it load the file and show everything inside it in a JList and when I click it.. It shows the line in a textarea.. But I want the Jlist to display only the number in the list and when I click it. It displays the rest of the Characters in the rest of the string in the line

this must be the content of the data.dat

1 lol 
2 lol 
3 lol 
4 lol 
5 lol

Comment: @AndrewThompson Please read the texts below the 2nd codes I post..
How can I make it Happen?

Comment: @JFetz2191 this is really a another question.  The short answer is yes